# Keep the architecture of table with multiple elements in one cell while crawling in R

Tags: r, dataframe, html

In the webpage, there is a kind of table in the webpage which have more than one element in one cell. I can crawl the content in the table by following code, but I could not bind these elements as their webpage architecture. Do we have some methods to combine these element perfectly, or we should use other idea to get each element?

```
library(XML)   
dataissued <- "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/294320/browse?type=dateissued"
    ec_parsed <- htmlTreeParse(dataissued, encoding = "UTF-8", useInternalNodes = TRUE)

# gether content in table and build the dataframe
# title and introduction link of IR resource
item_title <- xpathSApply(ec_parsed, '//td[@headers="t1"]//a', xmlValue)
item_hrefs <- xpathSApply(ec_parsed, '//td[@headers="t1"]//a/@href')
# author and introduction link of IR resource
auth_name <- xpathSApply(ec_parsed, '//td[@headers="t2"]//a', xmlValue)
auth_hrefs <- xpathSApply(ec_parsed, '//td[@headers="t2"]//@href')
# publish date of IR resource
pub_date <- xpathSApply(ec_parsed, '//td[@headers="t3"]', xmlValue)
# whole content link of IR resource
con_link <- xpathSApply(ec_parsed, '//td[@headers="t3"]//a[@href]', xmlValue)

item_table <- cbind(item_title, item_hrefs, auth_name, auth_hrefs, pub_date, con_link)
colnames(item_table) <- c("t1", "href1", "t2", "href2", "t3", "t4", "href4")
```

I have tried many times but still cannot organise them as it should be, just like one paper may have several authors, and all the authors and their links should save in one "row", but now one author is in one row, and the title of paper totally reused. That makes the result messed up.

Comment: I get `con_link` empty and an error on the last line trying to assign 7 colnames to item_table which has 6 columns.  Could you please fix up the code.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I had explained that my code have some errors on combining the data which it crowled, and I have tried to fix it but nothing works. Appreciate for your attention on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to make a long data frame from that table:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

pg <- read_html("http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/294320/browse?type=dateissued")

# extract the columns

col1 <- html_nodes(pg, "td[headers='t1']")
col2 <- html_nodes(pg, "td[headers='t2']")
col3 <- html_nodes(pg, "td[headers='t3']")

# this is the way to get the full text column

col4 <- html_nodes(pg, "td[headers='t3'] + td")

# now, iterate over the rows; map_df() will bind all our data.frame's together

map_df(1:legnth(col1), function(i) {

  # extract the links

  a1 <- xml_nodes(col1[i], "a") 
  a2 <- xml_nodes(col2[i], "a")
  a4 <- xml_nodes(col4[i], "a")

  # put the row into a long data.frame for the row

  data_frame(      title = html_text(a1, trim=TRUE),
              title_link = html_attr(a1, "href"),
                  author = html_text(a2, trim=TRUE),
             author_link = html_attr(a2, "href"),
              issue_date = html_text(col3[i], trim=TRUE),
               full_text = html_attr(a4, "href"))

})
```

Comment: Thank you for your warmly help. It's very ashamed that I've never used all the package you used in the program above. And your neat code really awesome. But I still have two questions on it.
1. "map_df" is a "function", and not only the dataframe combined with it could not use common method to reveal, but also 

the content in the dataframe echoed in the console of Rstudio have mass code in it. 
2. After combine those elements, the reading method of generated dataframe need to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem during using "rvest" package is mess code. Even the parameter "encoding" has been used in the program, the result still have mess code. But the web page encoding is UTF-8. Such as:

```
library(rvest)
pg <- read_html("http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/294320/browse?type=dateissued", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

For my test, the best performance should be "XML", when I use getNodeset function, the result is right, no mess code at all. However, I only get the whole node, and could not gether each row of table with their structure.

```
library(XML)
pg <- "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/294320/browse?type=dateissued"
pg_tables <- getNodeSet(htmlParse(pg), "//table[@summary='This table browse all dspace content']")
# gether the node of whole table
papernode <- getNodeSet(pg_tables[[1]], "//td[@headers='t1']")
paper_hrefs <- xpathSApply(papernode[[1]], '//a/@href')
paper_name <- xpathSApply(papernode[[1]], '//a', xmlValue)
# gether authors in table
authnode <- getNodeSet(pg_tables[[1]], "//td[@headers='t2']")
# gether date in table
datenode <- getNodeSet(pg_tables[[1]], "//td[@headers='t3']")
```

With this program, I could get these "nodes" separatly. However, crawling the headers and their links seems getting harder. Because the result class of "getNodeSet" is not same as "html_nodes". How can we read the dataframe generated by "getNodeSet" automatically and extract the header and their links from these nodes in an exact way?